# How can I search for all files that are not user write able?

Tags: unix

How would I search for files that are not write able? I know I can use ls command to see all the files but I just want to see the files that are not user write able.

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I second that. You can even try googling stuff before asking such simple things.

Comment: i did and was couldn't find it otherwise i wouldn't be here asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to find files:

```
find -user $USER ! -perm -u=w
```

Details:

`-user` - context user

`!` - negation

`-perm` - permisssions

`-u=w` - user write permission

It can be written more concisely using:

```
find ! -writable
```

But I wanted to show that `find` is the tool to expose file/directory properties for search.

Answer (score 0):

using `ls -Rl` and pipe it to `grep` will give you what you need:

`ls -Rl | grep -e "^-r-"`